# Why is my .htaccess file not redirecting

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect using a .htaccess file and it's not working.  The syntax seems to be correct.  Does any one have any ideas what is incorrect?

```html
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
Redirect 301 /www.easycovertarp.com/ http://www.aeroindustries.com/products/easy-cover/
```

Comment: redirect local.aero.com to http://www.aeroindustries.com/products/easy-cover/

Comment: Is local.aero.com on a localhost? I.E. the full url being `localhost/local.aero.com/`?

Comment: I've changed the redirect will this work instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert this rule just below `RewriteBase` line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =local.aero.com
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.aeroindustries.com/products/easy-cover/ [L,R=301]
```

Ordering is important in mod_rewrite rules so this rule must be placed above shown WP rules.

Comment: what if the redirect is this instead? Redirect 301 /www.easycovertarp.com/ http://www.aeroindustries.com/products/easy-cover/

Comment: Change condition to `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.easycovertarp.com`